# ORDER BY without column name

Tags: mysql, sql

**Solved**
Is it possible to execute a `ORDER BY` clause without column name?

I am following this tutorial on mysql: https://youtu.be/7S_tz1z_5bA?t=4736 (At 1 hour, 18 minutes in)

> #### MySQL Tutorial for Beginners
>
> [image]

In this tutorial it is mentioned that if no column name is specified with the `ORDER BY` clause it considers primary key as the column by default. but this dosen't seem to work when I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY
```

as said in the tutorial.

[Note] `customer_id` is the primary key in the customers table.**

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Why have you tagged this question with both MySQL and SQL Server? They're two separate systems with very different SQL dialects.

Comment: I watched the chapter of that linked video that covers `ORDER BY` - at no point does the instructor use `ORDER BY` without _something_ following it (whether a column name or a column ordinal). If there's another point in the video where the instructor does it and it works please edit your question to mention the timecode.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: While MySQL *may* behave this way in practice, theoretically it's not true, and never was. If you want rows returned in a specific order then you must always include an ORDER BY clause

Comment: _"Is it possible to execute a ORDER BY clause without column name?"_ ..umm No. The video is partly to blame for this misunderstanding because the narrator leave the `ORDER BY` clause hang there without defining any column while "explaining about the default ordering by `PRIMARY KEY` when you execute a query". But if you watch that part again, you'll see that the query with hanging `ORDER BY` was not executed. I was waiting for the narrator to execute it (I know it will return an error).. but it doesn't happen

Comment: I have misunderstood the tutorial. i think what the instructor was trying to say is that if we execute a query the default ordering is done according to the ```PRIMARY KEY```. thank you all for responding. it was my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this tutorial it is mentioned that if no column name is specified with the ORDER BY clause it considers primary key as the column by default.

Either the tutorial is 100% wrong on this fundamental point and you should probably find another tutorial or you misinterpreted what it is saying (I'm not going to bother listening to it).

SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets (the "multi" just means that duplicates are allowed).  When you execute a query with no `ORDER BY`, the results are in an arbitrary order.  That order may or may not correspond to the ordering of the primary key.  That order may change from one execution to the next.

Now, in practice -- and particularly on small tables -- the results do seem to be in the order that they are stored in the data pages.  This ordering may be based on insertion order or based on a clustered index.  If you have a primary key defined in MySQL, then I think that will always be used as the clustered index.  **However, there are no guarantees that a query with no `ORDER BY` will be in any particular order, even if it looks to be true on small datasets.**

Syntactically, `ORDER BY` is a clause that requires *something* to follow it.  Many things are allowed:

- A compatible column in one of the original tables.
- Any column or expression in the `SELECT`.
- Any column alias defined in the `SELECT`.
- A compatible expression that *could* be in the `SELECT`, including window functions.
- A compatible subquery.
- An integer that references the `SELECT` expressions by position.

The word "compatible" in the above list is intended to take care of aggregation queries, where you need any expression accessible after the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Order by clause as part of query is specifically used to sort rows of query result set.By  default rows contained into result set are sorted by primary key column in ascending order.But if there is requirement to render result set in specific order then column specification into order by clause is must which will let query execution engine to execute query in defined manner

Answer (score -2):

If you have `ORDER BY` clause, you should give the key/column to be ordered by. Else it will give you a syntax error.

Comment: According to the standard, leaving off the `ORDER BY` clause results in undefined order.  Due to practical implementation details databases often end up reading through index order for simple queries, but this is not guaranteed, and is almost never observed with queries of any real size.  Even if this were the case, it's almost never want you want, anyways: table primary keys are almost always surrogate keys, and the values are meaningless, so the order of the source in such a case is rarely relevant.